# I am trying to program a simple game in which when a ball moves to a certain area the view changes to another view (the next level)

Tags: ios5, xcode4, storyboard

```
   if(CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, transitionArea.frame))
{
    FirstLevel2ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstlevel2"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];



}
```

here is my code but when the ball intersects with the transition area nothing happens
I am using storyboard on Xcode 4, which I am relatively new to

I've tried many things but none have worked so any help would be great, thanks!